# Why Can't I Use Laptops in 24/7 Server Environment?

Tags: laptop

I've built an Internet service that's going to handle a few hundred simultaneous users. It'll run smoothly on a grid of VMWare+Windows 2008 servers.

Why can't I use laptops instead of traditional towers and rack-mountable servers for my hardware infrastructure? No one ever does this. I'm sure there's a good reason for it. But what is it? The laptops have the 1gb ethernet, enough ram, enough storage, and enough cpu power to do the job. Is it an overheating issue? Are laptops just not meant to be on for 24/7 under heavy load? What will happen to them under heavy load?

I'd ideally like to stick one laptop next to another, in a vertical fashion, like sliding books into a shelf. Each one would be kept upright using bookends and doorstops. I'd prefer to use something other than bookends and doorstops because each bookend has a duck-head on top of it and the "beak" portion of the bookend would take up too much horizontal room.

The bookend question is secondary though. The real question is: Why can't people effectively use laptops instead of traditional servers in a 24/7 server environment. And if they can… why DON'T they. And if this is feasible, what can I use to stabilize the laptops instead of a bookend/doorstop?

(I have access to a bunch of seized/unused laptops. That's why I ask.)

Comment: The cost of the server hardware itself is such a small component of the total cost of ownership (when you obviously don't need heavy CPU horsepower or lots of disk space) that this really makes very little sense.

Comment: true, but you can't beat free. Will the motherboards melt or something if taxed too much? Also, with traditional heavy servers, I'd have to pay someone to mount it in the cabinet.

Comment: I/O really sucks on laptops.  They usually come with a 5400rpm small drive.

Comment: Thanks, Zoredache. That's good to know. Most of the laptops would be running IIS and performing cpu-intensive calculations. But you're right, I will need at least one database... so it sounds like that might be a bottleneck for the read/writes.

Comment: Put the laptops on eBay and use the money to buy some real servers.

Comment: Michael, thanks. It's a good idea but I don't have permission to sell. Use them or lose them.

Comment: In that case, please post the location of your dumpster.

Comment: LOL no, they'll probably just sit in a closet somewhere. Maybe I'll try using them as calc/iis machines and get a dedicated database server [non-laptop].

Comment: If you do this, post it on hackernews.

Comment: If you do this please let us know the name of your company so that we can all ensure we never deal with it.

Comment: It's not a company smart-ass.... but wow, what a really clever comeback! Perhaps you can use the virtual "up votes" you'll receive to buy some gold pieces in World of Warcraft.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers I suspect he works for a law enforcement or other government agency. You generally don't get much choice in whether you deal with those or not.

Comment: You guys are all wrong... To the OP, just do this with [Mac Mini's](http://www.apple.com/macmini/) instead of laptops! [Here's a perfect example](http://www.macminicolo.net/facility.html)...

Comment: OK, this comment section is getting way too long. Join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) if you want to talk to some of the world's top sysadmins (at least in our own minds).

Comment: ewwhite, actually an interesting link. There are a lot of co-location places sprouting up in Vegas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Laptops don't have multiple processors
- Laptops don't have 192+Gb of RAM
- Laptop CPUs are often low-power versions (both in terms of watts and processing power)
- Laptop CPUs often put themselves into low-power mode to conserve battery power
- Laptops don't have RAID disk systems
- Laptops don't have Fibre Channel HBAs
- Laptops don't have mutliple ethernet ports
- Laptops don't have 10GbE ethernet
- Laptops don't have hot-swappable components (like disks)
- Laptops don't have upgradable processors
- Laptops don't have upgradable RAM (well, some don't)
- Laptops don't have a 24x7 duty cycle
- Laptops don't have OOB management
- Laptops don't have 4hr service contracts
- Laptops don't have support from software vendors

The list goes on...

- Laptops don't have TCP Offload
- Laptops don't have iSCSI offload
- Laptops don't have fast disks (5200 RPM usually, SSD excepted)
- Laptops don't have huge disk capacities
- Laptops don't have particularly good cooling

Comment: But... but... Beowulf clusters! *(I keed, I keed...)*

Comment: @Mark, that's just being picky. We all know that laptops are the most reliable machines ever built and have never had a failure. ;)

Comment: @WesleyDavid - well actually, if you're the likes of Google or AWS then you can afford to have as many SPOF as you like. It's well known Google have really commodity servers. That's because they have *millions* of them and can route around failures. Sort of like RAID but for entire racks, rather than individial disks :p

Comment: [Mac Mini Colo...](http://www.macminicolo.net/facility.html)

Comment: @ewwhite - it was only a matter of time... as I said, if you build your infrastructure around it you can do this sort of thing, but just *look* at the number of machines they have

Comment: `Laptops don't have TCP Offload` - People use TOE? :)

Comment: @MDMarra - irrelevant; the fact is they don't have it (and fwiw the TOE alleges to save a massive amount of processing power on a maxed out 10GbE connection)

Comment: Dammit, I tried, but I can't resist the urge to point out that my laptop has multiple processors, >192GB RAM (RAM *disks* count as RAM, right?), doesn't go into a lower power mode, has multiple Ethernet ports, mirror RAID for the boot disk, hot swappable disks, upgradable RAM and CPU, OOB, a 4hr service contact, huge disk capacity and great support from Microsoft [for Windows 7]. :p  (It's still not good for use as a server... though might make a better server than some of the circa 2006 servers we do actually use as servers...)

Comment: @HopelessN00b - what the hell laptop do you have?

Comment: Cooling... Wish I had a quarter for every time my HP Elitebook shut down from overheating.

Answer (score 4):

The same reason you can't compete  in an F1 race using your Hyundai Elantra.

Laptops are designed for limited single-user use.  They do not perform well in the place of servers, because servers are designed for resilience, redundancy and continuous operation serving multiple clients.

You're also obviously not looking very closely, because laptops and servers have different types of RAM, CPUs, NICs (etc), and a 3.6 Ghz quad core Xeon is nowhere near the same thing as the quad core CPU in your laptop.  (Three guesses which one is more powerful.)

If all you're doing is looking at the raw numbers, I would point out that the engine in my cheap, mass-produced car has a large displacement (bigger number of liters) than an F1 race car... but that doesn't actually tell you anything about which vehicle is faster, does it?)

If you really think your laptops are up to the task, set up a laptop and try to serve up a website (or whatever) to a few dozen or hundred clients at a time.  You'll get slow performance and slews of errors, because laptops and laptop components are not designed for it.

Comment: the site isn't letting me accept your answer with the checkmark. The performance with the laptop(s) is actually great... but I don't have to a way to test them under the load of 100+ users. I'm curious what kind of errors might occur. Perhaps I'll come up with a way to simulate this.

Comment: @ChadDecker No, it's really not.  It might be great for single use client-side apps, but will not perform well on server-side apps with multiple users accessing it.  Among other problems, you'll run short on I/O metric, memory bandwidth, CPU resources and error correction (or a lack thereof).

Answer (score 4):

> The real question is: Why can't people effectively use laptops instead of traditional servers in a 24/7 server environment.

- Because they don't have hot-swap power supplies or hard disks.
- They don't have user-servicable CPUs.
- They don't (usually) support more than 1 internal HDD, so RAID is out of the question.
- They don't have LOM.
- They don't support ECC/FB memory.
- They're not on any VMWare or Hyper-V HCL.

Plus, it would be silly.

Comment: what's LOM? xxxx

Comment: @ChadDecker http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_out_management